# Storyboard and one to many view controller

Tags: xcode

I'm writing an app that has a one to many view controller relation.

The main vc, say A can call all other (B, C, ...), but the sub vc's can just give control back to A.

I have defined the relations by segues inside the storyboard and switching between the vc's works. The sub vc's should be able to save their status during the lifetime of the app.

Now I have seen, that every segue creates a new vc. So I have to pass status data back to A. That's why I have created a delegate protocol in vc B, to pass data back to A. The data come back in A as expected. But when I do the next prepareForSegue in A to switch back to B I am also in a new object of vc A but the data is in the old object for vc A.

Do I really have to save the data on the filesystem to have them available all the app live time? Is that correct or am I missing something?

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers

Comment: found the missing information [->Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820769/storyboard-segue-unloads-original-view-controller?rq=1) - I used segue to return back and that createD the new objects